# How to stream audio from raspberry pi to android phone?

Tags: raspbian, audio, raspbian-jessie, android, streaming

I want to use my android phone as speaker for my rpi 3 with raspbian jessie. 
As I unerstood I can't use my phone as bluetooth speaker.
The only solution I found is to use Soundwire. However I'm not able to install Soundwire server on rpi(it has special version for pi). I get following error:

Error: No default input service

An error occured while opening the portaudio stream

Error message: PortAudio not initialized

Error -10000 opening audio input device

Are there any way to stream audio to my android phone?

Comment: Why would you want to use a phone as a speaker? Why not connect speakers directly to the Pi?

Comment: Because I have connected rpi to the large display and I want to be able to use headphones when I'm not close to pi. Also I don't have any free speakers and  it would be nice to use phone instead.

Comment: What are your streamer options? What would you like to stream to your phone? (I'm using Logitech Media Server, MPD to stream)

Comment: Hey man sorry for bumping old thread. I have the exact same problem, do you have any fix?

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to use a DLNA server on the Raspberry Pi and a DLNA renderer on the android phone. This is also sometimes know as upnp ... a upnp server which live streams your Pi audio and the renderer on your phone.

Plenty of phone apps to do that.

Matt

Comment: From experience, most phone apps which support DLNA will support UPNP. Either way, you can also install a DLNA specific application, which is still a solution - so too is installing an airport express player !

Comment: You're right, although I still think it is misleading to say DLNA "is also sometimes known as upnp".  http://www.linksys.com/us/support-article?articleNum=138198 I upvoted this the first time I read it but I've deleted my previous comment -- it was *even more* misleading ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'm the SoundWire lead developer. If you're running SoundWire Server as root, try running as a regular user. If that doesn't help then there's a problem with your audio configuration. Check that pulse audio is installed and has been set up according to the SoundWire Server README file.

Your audio player should also use pulse audio, or SoundWire probably won't work. SoundWire doesn't use Pulse directly, it uses Portaudio, so any audio configuration that can monitor the audio output and be captured by Portaudio will work. However we have only tested SoundWire on Linux/RPi with pulse audio.

Answer (score 0):

> As I understood I can't use my phone as Bluetooth speaker.

**Sure you can**. Youmust buy a USB [BT Adapter](https://www.conrad.de/de/bluetooth-stick-40-raspberry-pi-kompatibel-448876.html) and stick it in your raspi.
[And then read this here.](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=68779)

Comment: Thank you, but in the guide audio from the phone is streamed to the rpi.I need it backwards.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, there is [UV4L](http://linux-projects.org) for audio streaming from/to the rpi.